# How decimal value consider at next round off value in java

Tags: java, regex, spring, performance, math

I'm trying to convert a decimal to a rounded value. I need the easiest way to round the value.

For example, my sample values:

```
12.63
4.12
22.00
7.96
0.15
```

Expected result:

```
13
5
22
8
1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to round a number to n decimal places in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple. You can use Java Math class for this. Math.ceil() method rounds off the specified double value and you can then convert it to int by using type casting.

```
(int)Math.ceil(double value)
```